# how to keep checked items at top of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

i have a long list with a grouped items , my visitors choose items from this list and submit the form , i need to keep the checked items at the top of the list after they submit the form or on page load , because that make them know which items they have chosen before at any time they get into the form without scrolling the whole list

my list with checked items looks like :

```
<div class="main-div">

    <div class="group-title"><span>group one title</span></div>

         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-1" value="1" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-1">item1</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-2" value="2" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-2">item2</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-3" value="3" name="item_name[]" checked ><label for="item-3">item3</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-4" value="4" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-4">item4</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-5" value="5" name="item_name[]" checked ><label for="item-5">item4</label></div>

    <div class="group-title"><span>group two title</span></div>

         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-6" value="6" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-6">item6</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-7" value="7" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-7">item7</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-8" value="8" name="item_name[]" checked ><label for="item-8">item8</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-9" value="9" name="item_name[]"checked ><label for="item-9">item9</label></div>
         <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-10"value="10" name="item_name[]"><label for="item-10">item10</label></div>

</div>
```

i need it to look like a following :

```
<div class="main-div">

       <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-3" value="3" name="item_name[]" checked ><label for="item-3">item3</label></div>
       <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-5" value="5" name="item_name[]" checked ><label for="item-5">item4</label></div>
       <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-8" value="8" name="item_name[]" checked ><label for="item-8">item8</label></div>
       <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-9" value="9" name="item_name[]" checked ><label for="item-9">item9</label></div>

  <div class="group-title"><span>group one title</span></div>

     <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-1" value="1" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-1">item1</label></div>
     <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-2" value="2" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-2">item2</label></div>
     <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-4" value="4" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-4">item4</label></div>


   <div class="group-title"><span>group two title</span></div>

     <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-6" value="6" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-6">item6</label></div>
     <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-7" value="7" name="item_name[]" ><label for="item-7">item7</label></div>
     <div class="items"><input type="checkbox" id="item-10" value="10" name="item_name[]"><label for="item-10">item10</label></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.main-div .group-title').each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('.group-title', '.items').data('group', this);
    });

    $('.main-div .items').has('input:checked').prependTo('.main-div');

    $('.main-div').on('change', 'input',function(){
        var $item = $(this).closest('.items');
        if(this.checked){
            $item.insertBefore($('.main-div .group-title').first())
        }else{
            $item.appendTo($item.data('group'))
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6mN7J/)

Comment: your code is working well but if you could make it works on page load only not instant that would be soo great ; thank you

Comment: every time the page is loaded i want the code to get all the checked items and put them on the top of the list  and stop working till the page is loaded again

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use jQuery's `before` and `after` code. It looks like this:

```
function swapElements(elm1, elm2) {
    var parent1, next1,
        parent2, next2;

    parent1 = elm1.parentNode;
    next1   = elm1.nextSibling;
    parent2 = elm2.parentNode;
    next2   = elm2.nextSibling;

    parent1.insertBefore(elm2, next1);
    parent2.insertBefore(elm1, next2);
}
```

This is just the skeleton. Nice question, so I am working on this.